# C++ smart pointer counter

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

```
class Blob{
public:
    Blob();
    Blob(initializer_list<string> il);

private:
    shared_ptr<vector<string>> data;
};


Blob:: Blob() : data(make_shared<vector<string>>()) {}
Blob:: Blob(initializer_list<string> il) : data(make_shared<vector<string>>(il)) {}

Blob<string> b1; //empty Blob
{ //new scope
    Blob<string> b2 = {"a","b","the"};
    b1 = b2;//b1 and b2 share the same elements
}//b2 is destroyed, but the elements in b2 must not be destroyed
 //b1 points to the elements originally created in b2
```

My question is: why shouldn't b1 on line 4 be destroyed? In my opinion, assigning one **shared_pointer** to another increments the count of the right-hand operand and decrements the count in the left-hand operand. 
I think on line4, b1 goes to 0(counter), so it should be destroyed.

Comment: It's so because it is... well, shared

Comment: What is this Blob class?

Comment: b1 is object not smart pointer, so there is no such rules for an object, am i right?

Comment: Question is unclear, but you are assigning from b2 to b1 so after inner scope data from b2 are in b1, b2 is destroyed ... .Scope of b1 is still valid

Comment: Blob class is equivalent to std::shared_ptr

Comment: Without the class `Blob` the question is meaningless.

Comment: I edited the question, now the class is clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna assume you `Blob` class is equivalent to `std::shared_ptr` :

```
{ // ----------------------------------------->  // Function scope

    Blob<string> b1; // ---------------------->  // b1 is empty : b1.use_count() == 0

    { // ------------------------------------->  // New scope

        Blob<string> b2(new std::string("Foo");  // b2 holds "Foo" : b2.use_count() == 1

        b1 = b2; // -------------------------->  // Assigning b2 to b1:
                                                 // b1 doesn't do anything because
                                                 // it was not holding any pointer.
                                                 // b1 now owns "Foo" as well
                                                 // and b1.use_count() == b2.use_count == 2

    } // ------------------------------------->  // b2 goes out of scope so it is removed
                                                 // and its reference counting is decreased.
                                                 // Since the count doesn't equal 0, nothing is done.

} // ----------------------------------------->  // b1 goes out of scope.
                                                 // The reference counting decreases again.
                                                 // Since the count is now 0,
                                                 // b1 deletes its internal pointer and releases "Foo".
```

In your question, you seem not to distinct `b1` from the pointer it is responsible of.
`b1` is not a pointer so it is released when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Thank you, here is the constructor of my class, `Blob:: Blob() : data(make_shared<vector<string>>()) {}` so i think b1 is a pointer but points to nothing.

Comment: let's say b1 is pointing to something, like `Blob<string> b1 = {"a"};` then , in `b1 = b2`, will b1 be destroyed?

Comment: Why don't you try it by yourself? Just add some debugging in a destructor and you'll understand!